# Group status code in access log

Tags: linux

In my access log, I got a response like

```
6346 10.208.65.246 37.228.105.117 - - [03/Feb/2014:04:00:42 -0500] 0 "GET /action/1.php HTTP/1.0" 200 2284 "a.com/abc.php" "Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.33361/34.1088; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10" 122.161.232.180, 37.228.105.117, 37.228.111.13, 10.208.65.24
```

Can I use `grep` to group response code(200) occurrence with count when there is  `/action/1.php` in log?

Expected Output:

200 10   // here 200 is status code and 10 is count

302 80

Comment: can you give an example of the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but this should do the trick:

```
cat htaccess.log  | cut -d"\"" -f3 | cut -d" " -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```